# LDAP Client change Unix and Samba password

Tags: password, samba, ldap

I have to work in a mixed Windows/Linux world as far as desktop clients are concerned.  I've got a central OpenLDAP server with Samba3 that serves a fake windows domain which keeps the Windows guys happy.

I've then set up the Ubuntu clients to authenticate via LDAP which keeps them happy.

Heres where I'm falling over, on Windows if a user changes their password the Unix and Samba passwords get updated. Great.

On Ubuntu, only the unix password gets updated so next time they use a Windows machine they can't log in/have to use their old password.

What is the preferred solution to updating both passwords? Should I just install likewise-open on Ubuntu and make it join the fake Windows domain?

It just seems odd to my mind to make an Ubuntu server pretend to be a Windows server so that an Ubuntu client can pretend to be a Windows client logging into an Ubuntu server pretending to be a Windows server.

Any info would be appreciated.